# How can I find element by xpath in Chrome options python selenium

Tags: python

I am facing some difficulities with this,
(It's Not Finished Yet)

```
import webbrowser
import time

url1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8KRzm-HUcc'
chrome_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab(url1)
time.sleep(12)***.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]').click()***
```

How can I find an element by xpath without writing "Driver.find_element_by_xpath" because whenever I am not using "Driver.find_element_by_xpath" I get this error:

```
**attributeerror 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'**
```

Help is appreciated, I am new to coding and I still don't get some things...

Comment: Also the reason why I don't want to write driver.find... is because I don't want to open chrome as a webdriver.

Comment: what on earth are you doing in that last line?

Comment: well the code is not finished, and I can't get it finished unless I have this find element by xpath fixed which I don't know how to do... I need to keep time.sleep(12), however when I wrote driver.find_element_by_xpath(...) I get error in python code, saying it's undentified...

Comment: So first of all I had the same thought like @Chris. Second you have to use some sort of WebDriver to use Selenium. There are multiple for different Webbrowsers. If you don't want that the Browser "pop's up" then you can run your driver in ```-headless``` mode. ```find_element_by_xpath()``` is a function of the WebDriver. Because of that you have to use the WebDriver, otherwise there is no "connection" between your programm and the Browser. I would suggest to watch some tutorials on yt, because this looks like you have to learn a lot before you get this code to run.

Comment: Alrighty thank you, God bless